# Modifying the html codes of Github

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I have used the codes of the following link to create slideshows,

[here is the link](https://gist.github.com/fidelisrafael/6599214#file-slideshow-html)

it does work for four images, I have 5 images, I could not sort it out for 5 images,

Can anyone help me please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to fix at first the width is calculated 710 * N where N is in the example 4. So you need to patch this line first from:

```
width: 2840px; /* 710 * 4 */
```

to:

```
width: 3550px /* 710 * 5 */
```

The next step is to extend the keyframe to show the fifth element, then you also need to recalculate the percentage with is not hard from:

```
@keyframes slideshow {
    0%  { margin-left:  0.5%; }
    25% { margin-left: -100%; }
    50% { margin-left: -200%; }
    75% { margin-left: -300%; }
}
```

to:

```
@keyframes slideshow {
    0%  { margin-left:  0.5%; }
    20% { margin-left: -100%; }
    40% { margin-left: -200%; }
    60% { margin-left: -300%; }
    80% { margin-left: -400%; }
}
```

You can omit AFIK now all other prefixes. Check also this fiddler as example: http://jsfiddle.net/avze5shj/

---

Based on the comments I extended the example with a better timing: http://jsfiddle.net/avze5shj/1/

Comment: Thank you@rekir, when I use it , I have problem  with  transition, Does not change with  different times. I want to have 10 second pause in each slide. Any solution?